# WordPress REST API Authentication Using Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, wordpress-rest-api

I'm attempting to use [cookie authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) for WordPress REST API access using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), however the auth is failing with the following error.

> 403: Cookie Nonce is Invalid

I'm using the following script to connect to the API.

```
const headers = new Headers({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'X-WP-Nonce': WPAPI.nonce
});  

fetch(WPAPI.root + 'my-endpoint/upload/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

When I switch from using Fetch to [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) it works as expected.

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', WPAPI.root + 'my-endpoint/upload/', true);
request.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', WPAPI.nonce);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Is it possible there an issue with the way headers are being sent in the Fetch method?

Answer (score 6):

WordPress nonce authentication requires the use of cookies and by default Fetch doesn't send those along. You can use the credentials option to make this work:

```
fetch(endpoint, {
  credentials: 'same-origin'
})
```

https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Came across my post from 4 years ago looking for the same issue :)
This solves the problem.

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-WP-Nonce' : my_var.nonce
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
const content = await response.json();
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but maybe helpful for other readers as I added code specifically for **fetch()** promise according to this question.

WordPress uses [nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/nonces/) automatically within their cookies, as I found out.

### Solution: Permission Callback function checking for cookie

**WordPress**: version 5.7.2
**PHP**: version 7.4
**host**: hostmonster.com
**client**: Windows 10
**browsers**: tested on Chrome, Firefox, even Edge  worked

**Code** (**PHP** code in function.php of your installed theme):

```php
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    /**
     * Register here your custom routes for your CRUD functions
     */
    register_rest_route( 'my-endpoint/v1', '/upload/', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE, // = 'GET'
            'callback' => 'get_data',
            // Always allow, as an example
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
        ),
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE, // = 'POST'
            'callback' => 'create_data',
            // Here we register our permissions callback
            // The callback is fired before the main callback to check if the current user can access the endpoint
            'permission_callback' => 'prefix_get_private_data_permissions_check',
        ),
    ));
});

// The missing part:
// Add your Permission Callback function here, that checks for the cookie
// You should define your own 'prefix_' name, though

function prefix_get_private_data_permissions_check() {
    
    // Option 1: Password Protected post or page:
    // Restrict endpoint to browsers that have the wp-postpass_ cookie.
    if ( !isset($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_'. COOKIEHASH] )) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_forbidden', esc_html__( 'OMG you can not create or edit private data.', 'my-text-domain' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    };

    // Option 2: Authentication based on logged-in user:
    // Restrict endpoint to only users who have the edit_posts capability.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_forbidden', esc_html__( 'OMG you can not create or edit private data.', 'my-text-domain' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    };
 
    // This is a black-listing approach. You could alternatively do this via white-listing, by returning false here and changing the permissions check.
    return true;
};

function create_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->query(...);

    return $result;
}

function get_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $data = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * from `data`');

    return $data;
}
```

Make sure to include in your HTML page `credentials: 'same-origin'` in your HTTP request, as stated correctly in previous answers and comments above.

**Code** (**HTML** with inline `<script> ... </script>`):

```html
<script>

// Here comes the REST API part:
// HTTP requests with fetch() promises

function getYourData() {
  let url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/my-endpoint/v1/upload/';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin', // <-- make sure to include credentials
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token  <-- not needed, WP does not check for it
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => get_success(response))
  .catch(error => failure(error));
};

function insertYourData(data) {
  let url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/my-endpoint/v1/upload/';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin', // <-- make sure to include credentials
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        //'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token  <-- not needed, WP does not check for it
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => create_success(response))
  .catch(error => failure(error));
};

// your Success and Failure-functions:

function get_success(json) {
  // do something here with your returned data ....
  console.log(json);
};

function create_success(json) {
  // do something here with your returned data ....
  console.log(json);
};

function failure(error) {
  // do something here ....
  console.log("Error: " + error);
};

</script>
```

### Final thoughts:

Is `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token` necessary in header of HTTP request?

After some testing, I realized that `if ( !isset($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_'. COOKIEHASH] )) { ...` within the **Permission Callback** not only checks if the Cookie is set on client browser, **but it seems also to check its value (the JWT token)**.

Because I dobble checked as with my initial code, passing a false token, eliminating the cookie, or leaving session open but changing in the back-end the password of site (hence WordPress would create a new token, hence value of set `wp_postpass_` cookie would change) and all test went correctly - **REST API blocked, not only verifying presence of cookie, but also its value** (which is good - thank you WordPress team).

**Sources:**
I found following resource concerning above thoughts in the [FAQ section](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/):

[Why is the REST API not verifying the incoming Origin header? Does this expose my site to CSRF attacks?](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#why-is-the-rest-api-not-verifying-the-incoming-origin-header-does-this-expose-my-site-to-csrf-attacks)

> Because the WordPress REST API does not verify the Origin header of
> incoming requests, public REST API endpoints may therefore be accessed
> from any site. This is an intentional design decision.
>
> However, WordPress has an existing CSRF protection mechanism which
> uses nonces.

And according to my testing so far, **the WP-way of authentication works perfectly well**.

### Thumbs up  for the WordPress team

Additional 2 sources from the WordPress **REST API Handbook**:

[REST API Handbook / Extending the REST API / Routes and Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/)
[REST API Handbook / Extending the REST API / Adding Custom Endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

And 1 source form WordPress **Code Reference** concerning `rest_cookie_check_errors()` function:

[Reference / Functions / rest_cookie_check_errors()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_cookie_check_errors/)

For those interested in full story of my findings, following link to my thread with answers, code snippets and additional findings.

[How to force Authentication on REST API for Password protected page using custom table and fetch() without Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/391515/how-to-force-authentication-on-rest-api-for-password-protected-page-using-custom)